# compute $\int_\gamma \sin(y-x)\ dx +2xy + \sin(x-y) \ dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, vector-fields, line-integrals

The question is
$$ \int_\gamma \sin(y-x)\ dx +\left(2xy + \sin(x-y)\right) \ dy, \quad \gamma:y=\sqrt{x}, \ \ 0\leq x\leq 1$$
I've tried to solve it like this:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sin(\sqrt{t}-t) +t+ \sin(t-\sqrt{t}) \ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\ dt \quad\text{with} \  \ \gamma:r(t)=(t,\sqrt{t}) $$

How should i proceed from here ?
Any suggestion would be great, thanks

Comment: I think there are some errors: We have $dx\neq dy$ since $dx=dt$ but $dy=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}dt$. And where is the $2xy$ part?

Comment: $2xy$ is with $dx$ or $dy$?

Comment: It seems that you have a typo in your integral.

Comment: I was unclear sorry, $Q=2xy+\sin(x-y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_\gamma \sin(y-x)\ dx +\left(2xy + \sin(x-y)\right) \ dy$

$= \int_\gamma \sin(y-x)\ dx +\left(\sin(x-y)\right) \ dy \ + \ \int_\gamma 2xy \ dy$

But please note that $\big(\sin(y-x), \sin(x-y)\big)  = \nabla f(x,y) \ $ where $\ f(x,y) = \cos(y-x)$ and $f(1,1) - f(0,0) = 1 -1 = 0$.

So the line integral for part of the vector field is zero and all you are left with is to find -

$\displaystyle \int_{\gamma} 2xy \ dy = \int_0^1 t \ dt = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Q is $2xy+\sin(x-y)$ so $F$ is not conservative vector field, sorry i was unclear

Comment: OK so contribution of the part of the vector field in my answer is zero. So all you need to work on is $\int_{\gamma} \ 2xy \ dy$

Comment: Thank you Math Lover , your answer is correct but since this is the first time that i see a vector field being partially conservative, i wonder 
what theorem have you used for this and what is called such a vector filed? I thought a vector filed is called conservative if the requirement $Q'_x=P'_y$ would be met for the whole vector field but now the requirement is met only partially?

Comment: Thank you i see it now :)

Comment: @simon when you see vector fields having plus or minus components, you should check  if splitting it helps. It is possible that part of the vector field is path independent and may be even zero... and hopefully the one that requires more work to integrate :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$\int \sin(t-\sqrt{t})(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}-1)dt=$$
$$\cos(t-\sqrt{t})$$